# Python unittest, datetime

Tags: python, testing, python-unittest

My problem is:
In my following test, everything is working today but not will work tomorrow, I'm a beginner and did try a lot of options, but I failed, I,m trying pass "now" as a parameter but with no success until now.
I have to stop the "datetime.now()" and put one fixed date to can test all variations.
I had god progress until here, but I'm stuck on this
Can you help me, please? 
Thank you.
Flavio

```py
import unittest
from datetime import datetime


def get_last_name_and_birthday(name, d):
    x = name.split()
    dob = d.split("-")
    year, month, day = int(dob[2]), int(dob[1]), int(dob[0])
    user_birthday = datetime(year, month, day)
    return x[-1], user_birthday


def calc_days(user_birthday):
    now = datetime.now()
    if user_birthday < now:
        birthday = datetime(now.year + 1, user_birthday.month, user_birthday.day)
        return (birthday - now).days + 1
    else:
        birthday = datetime(now.year, user_birthday.month, user_birthday.day)
        return (birthday - now).days + 1


def generate_output(last_name, cd):
    if cd == 365:
        return "Hello Mr " + last_name + " Happy Birthday"
    elif cd < 365:
        return "Hello Mr " + last_name + " your birthday is in " + str(cd) + " days"
    else:
        return "Hello Mr " + last_name + " your birthday is in " + str(cd - 365) + " days"


def process_name_and_birthday(name, dob):
    last_name, user_birthday = get_last_name_and_birthday(name, dob)
    cd = calc_days(user_birthday)
    return generate_output(last_name, cd)


#name = input("type your full name: ")
#dob = input("type your date of birthday(dd-mm-yy): ")
#print(process_name_and_birthday(name, dob))



class BirthdayTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_same_day_birthday(self):
        self.assertEqual("Hello Mr Oliveira Happy Birthday", process_name_and_birthday("Flavio Oliveira", "11-06-1990"))


class DaysToBirthdayTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_days_to_birthday(self):
        self.assertEqual("Hello Mr Oliveira your birthday is in 9 days", process_name_and_birthday("Flavio Oliveira", "20-06-1978"))


class DaysToPassedBirthdayTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_how_many_days_passed_birthday(self):
        self.assertEqual("Hello Mr Oliveira your birthday is in 364 days", process_name_and_birthday("Flavio Oliveira", "10-06-1978"))


unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the following three lines under your import of `datetime`:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock
datetime = Mock(wraps=datetime)
datetime.now.return_value = datetime(2020, 6, 11, 20)
```

There is more information about the `mock` module here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock

Comment: Good to hear. If you don't mind, you can accept the answer (not that I am desperate for reputation points or something ;-)).

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have reputation enough to accept, sorry.